# Applying a function to a dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery, dynamic

To style my radio buttons I'd like to use a jQuery plugin that requires the following line of code:

```
$('input').iCheck();
```

It doesn't work though because my buttons are dynamically generated when user clicks. Is there any way to make the plugin (any plugin really) work for all elements including those dynamically generated?

EDIT: my code below, not sure if that will be very understandable.

The page has the markup for the modal window hardcoded:

```
<div id="fadeandscale">
    <div class="fadeandscale_inner"></div>
</div>
<a id='button_page2' class="egg_button"></a>
```

The .egg_button link opens the modal. A modal/lightbox jQuery plugin is then associated with this markup:

```
$('#fadeandscale').popup();
```

Then I execute a series of on() bindings.

```
function populate_modal(x) {

    var button_id = '#button_page' + x;
    var page_id = '#course_intro_page' + x;

    $(button_id).on('click', function() {   
        $('.fadeandscale_inner').empty(); 
        var a = $(page_id).html(); 
        **$('.fadeandscale_inner').html(a);**   // content is duplicated to modal
    });

}               
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    populate_modal(i);
}
```

Then I bind the radio button styling jQuery plugin to the input elements when clicking on the link that open the modal (which also triggers duplication of page content into the modal):

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".egg_button", function() {
    $('input').iCheck();
});
```

From the markup hardcoded in the page, a radio button:

```
<div class='options_section'>   
    <input type="radio" name="modal1" id="modal1_option1" value="The analysis of large volumes of data">
    <label for="modal1_option1">The analysis of large volumes of data</label>
</div>
```

Comment: search for css solution. not JS.

Comment: How do you create your buttons? Can you please add it's code?

Comment: They are regular radio buttons hardcoded in the DOM, then duplicated in a modal window where the jQuery plugin is supposed to intervene.

Comment: It is very possible that you are calling the function before the element is drawn on the screen. you must wait for your elements to appear on screen before calling the function

Answer (score 2):

If the items aren't present in the DOM on page load, then you can use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach a function to a dynamically generated element.

I'm not sure about how you are generating the buttons, but maybe this will put you on the right path:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "input", function() {
  $( this ).iCheck();
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, the updated code is:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".open_modal", function() {
      $( "input" ).iCheck();
});
```

Comment: Worked! I did: $('body').on('click', '.open_modal', function() { $('input').iCheck(); }); Perhaps you can put this code in your answer so I can validate it?

Comment: Sorry it actually works only once, then if I close the modal and click to open it again, the plugin doesn't work any longer...

Comment: I can't help you further without seeing your current code. `.on()` is the correct solution, but the exact implementation depends on what else you are doing. There are a lot of related questions that show up in the sidebar that you can look at.

Comment: I editer my question to add my code, but it's hard to sum up the logic of my code, not sure if what I added will make sense to anyone.

Comment: So the input that needs the `iCheck()` is in the modal? Maybe consider making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a class to all the dynamically generated elements. When you create a button add a css class attribute like this:

```
<button type="button" class="cls"></button>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$(".cls").on("click", function()
{
// You can use $(this) to get any specific attribute of the button clicked
});
```

Comment: The plugin is to be applied to radio buttons, which are dynamically generated when user clicks on some link.